# Get Back Button to work on parent page when iframe is involved

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, browser

I am working on a legacy app that has an iframe involved. The back button is working on the iframe and I need it to bypass the iframe and work on the parent window only.

Here is a dumbed down version of the issue and description of what I know.

the main page "index.html" has an iframe that is being added via javascript. It loads a.html, makes an ajax call that then does a window.location = "b.html" At this point if you use the back button it essentiallys makes the iframe go back to a.html and then redirects to b.html so you are effectively stuck on the page. If I remove the ajax call and do an window.location on load everything works ok. However given the architecture and what happen on the page I can't remove the Ajax call from the picture.

Here is the code I am looking at, let me know your thoughts on how to solve this issue. Also I should mention in Chrome 41 this isn't an issue, however the newer chrome 48 and 49 it is an issue. I tried history.replaceState but wasn't able to figure out a way to use it in this situation that made things work.

index.html

```
    <html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
hello world!
<div id="iframeContainer"></div>

<script>
    $(function () {

        var newIframe = document.createElement('iframe');
        newIframe.src = "a.html";
        newIframe.id = "A";

        document.getElementById("iframeContainer").appendChild(newIframe);

    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

a.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body style="background-color:#F00;">

    <script>
    $(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url:"b.html",
            complete:function(){
                window.location="b.html";
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

b.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body style="background-color:#00F;">
<script>
    $(function(){
    })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So I have a really hackish fix and I wonder if someone has any better ideas. I added a history.replaceState(null,null, "c.html"); to the a and b pages then on that page I have a window.top.history.back();

Comment: That hackish fix won't work because if you press the forward button it bounces you back...

Answer (score 1):

This is only possible in HTML5 compatible browsers, and it would go something like this..

This goes in the child frame..

```
// catch the back button click.
window.onpopstate = function(event) {
  // make the parent window go back
  top.history.back();
};
```

This also only works if both frames are in teh same domain.

Comment: Do you think this would work with the backspace key as well?

Comment: I added this code but it had no impact on the issue. I am not seeing the onpopstate function firing when I hit the back button or backspace key. I am using Chrome 49 and Firefox.